# ASP.NET How do you set the version number on a web app?

Tags: asp.net, version-control, visual-studio-2010

..like you can on other project types?

Comment: What Visual Studio Version are you using?

Comment: VS2010. Sorry for the ommision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends if its a compiled web application you can set it on the assembly. As you are saying like others I assume you are using VS 2005.

Microsoft changed their approach in VS 2005 to use a Web Site project instead of a Web Application Project. Have a look at this article for further details http://webproject.scottgu.com/

I would recommend converting your solution and then setting it via the AssemblyInfo.cs file. http://webproject.scottgu.com/

Might be worthwhile checking this out. 
[Versioning an ASP.NET web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446153/versioning-an-asp-net-web-app)

Comment: I am using VS2010. I have no AssemblyInfo file. How do I create one?

Comment: I understand your problem. I would recommend converting your solution to a Web Application Project and setting via the AssemblyInfo.cs file. http://webproject.scottgu.com/ 

Its not as daunting as it may sound. Should take you a couple of minutes.

Comment: Hmm. I didn't know that there were multiple web site projects in VS2010. I was thinking that article didn't apply. OK, if it does, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion within

```
/YourWebApplication/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
```

Comment: I am using VS2010. I have no AssemblyInfo file. How do I create one?

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
using System.Reflection;
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

and set your assemblyinfo.cs as

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]

[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.*")]
```

Comment: I am using VS2010. I have no AssemblyInfo file. How do I create one?